# How to remove string from my mode re write code

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a beginner in mod_rewrite and I have this mod_rewrite code

```
RewriteRule ^packages-(.*).html$ ./package_details.php?url=$1
```

that just does what I intend to do except I have a little problem: the resulting URLs have this `packages-` prefixed  (e.g 
`packages-london-delight.html`) to them when I just want it to be `london-delight.html` and when I try to remove "packages-" from the URL, the rewrite rule stops working. The code that I use for generating links is

```
<a href="packages-<?php echo $row->friendly_url;?>.html"><?php echo $row->pack_title;?> </a>
```

All I want is to have to have a clean SEO-friendly URL like `http://xxxxxxx/london-delight.html`

Sorry for the long post. Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Can't you just remove `packages-` from the rewrite rule and remove `packages-` from the code that generates the links?

Comment: Bingo! thank  you very much  Sir you solution worked but for strange reason when i did the same thing prior to posting this question yesterday it was giving me Server error  :)